# adding lines to a file when push button pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qfile, qtextstream

i want write a string to a text file when i press the button but no matter how much i press the button the string gets written on the first line on the text file so how can i do it?
My code inside the buttons function is this:

```
QFile filename(".../Save.txt");
filename.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);   
QTextStream stream(&filename);
QString str = "Line";
stream << str << endl;
```

Comment: "the string gets written on the first line on the text file" ... and this is not what you want?

Comment: yes it is but when is press the button again i want it to be written on second line

Comment: You need to open file in `Append` mode

Comment: Thanks alot guys i tried it and it works with append.